# Remove quotation marks between tags using regex

Tags: regex, ruby, xml, rubygems

I have been struggling with trying to remove all quotation marks in an XML-file within specific tags in my Ruby on Rails project. The simple question is this: How do I remove all existing `"` if, and only if, they are within the description tag in the XML-file (using gsub)?

Example

```
<xml attribute="stuff"><name>Two inch thing (2")</name><description>This thing is really "awesome"></description></xml>
```

so that it becomes

```
<xml attribute="stuff"><name>Two inch thing (2")</name><description>This thing is really awesome></description></xml>
```

I have been struggling with regex for a few hours without getting anywhere.

I.e.

```
myxml_file.gsub(<regex matching quotation marks>, "")
```

This is a part of a bigger problem where I use the gem "Ox" to parse XML-files using `Ox.load(myxml_file, mode: :hash)` to load the XML-file but the description parts hold CDATA which Ox seems to ignore (just sets it all to nil) so I do a gsub to remove the CDATA tags but then some description seems to include quotation marks which crashes the Ox load. So, this problem could (preferrably) be solved already in the Ox.load part, for example by telling it to ignore CDATA-tags...

Edit Upon request:

I fetch the XML-file (which is a product feed) from a url which is in this case gzipped (which I am quite sure does not affect the issue in case):

```
tmp_data = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(tmp_data))
data = gz.read 
@feed = Ox.load(data, mode: :hash)
```

The product descriptions in this case looks like this example (where I have added a " just for sake of the issue):

```
<products><product><merchant_deep_link>https://www.sportlala.se/lopning-40y-edition-2-pack-thundercrus/22361/express</merchant_deep_link><display_price>SEK319</display_price><merchant_product_id>05353-392410-XS</merchant_product_id><merchant_image_url>https://www.sportlala.se/images/products/22361/1905353_392410_40y_Edition_2-Pack_Set_F.png</merchant_image_url><merchant_category></merchant_category><search_price>319</search_price><merchant_name>Sportlala SE</merchant_name><category_id>0</category_id><aw_deep_link>...</aw_deep_link><category_name></category_name><last_updated></last_updated><product_name>40y Edition 2-Pack Thunder/Crus</product_name><aw_product_id>24553291137</aw_product_id><aw_image_url>https://images2.productserve.com/?w=200&amp;h=200&amp;bg=white&amp;trim=5&amp;t=letterbox&amp;url=ssl%3Awww.sportlala.se%2Fimages%2Fproducts%2F22361%2F1905353_392410_40y_Edition_2-Pack_Set_F.png&amp;feedId=35735&amp;k=477d0110b807fbbbcddc9fb74c52fc30c401ca4a</aw_image_url><delivery_cost></delivery_cost><data_feed_id>35735</data_feed_id><description><![CDATA[I detta paket f&aring;r du tv&aring; av Craft&#39;s absolut b&auml;sta baslager jerseys. Dessa "jerseys" har samlat det b&auml;sta fr&aring;n Craft&#39;s kollektioner och har den absolut h&ouml;gsta kvalit&eacute;n! &nbsp; Material: 100% Polyester]]></description><merchant_id>17150</merchant_id><currency>SEK</currency><store_price></store_price><language></language></product></products>
```

This will make the `description=nil` in the resulting hash from Ox which I am quite certain is due to the CDATA wrapping in the  tag (as it is always nil, no matter if there are quotation marks (") or not.

I did a gsub that removed the CDATA with a gsub (I removed it now but it was something like `.gsub("<description><![CDATA[", "<description>").gsub("]]</description>", "</description>")` which efffectively removed the CDATA but then brought out the quotation marks-issue.

So, this problem can either be solved on the (preferrably) "Ox load"-level  through some configuration that yet have not seen or by regexp on the "-marks that extends over the entire text.

Comment: Could you please show us a minimal example of the code that does not work?  Be sure to show what the code does wrong, and show what you would like it to do instead.  Any answers to the question as it is now would be pret guesses.

Comment: I don't understand the -3 on this question. It is simply a question about how to catch all quotation marks if, and only if, they are within the <description> tags. (I don't expect anyone to really solve the Ox part). I never really got anywhere with regex outside of catching ALL the text within description tags. Would that really add any information to the question, posting that?

Comment: My downvote was because you haven't shown us any code, even though almost half of the question talks about code.  That left me wondering whether you need a regular expression to act against the entire XML, or one to act against some specific string extracted from the XML by the library.  If the former, my answer would be that you can't, except in specific circumstances, reliably manipulate XML using regular expressions.  If the latter, then it should be possible to answer with a regular expression, but for that we need to see what XML substring the regular expression must act upon.

Comment: Ok. I see. I thought it would get too confusing mixing in too much of the XML and Ox things into the question and keep it as a strict regexp-question but I have updated my question now.

Comment: That's much better, thanks.  So would you say that the problem starts when using a regexp to remove the CDATA?  It really does sound like you'd be much better off using an XML library to manipulate the XML, and not regular expressions.

Comment: Well, it is already a problem when I load it with no regexp as the description is never fetched but rather set as nil. I have looked into SAX which probably would be better as my XML-files are often large (50-200 Mb) but it is just too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
s = '<xml attribute="stuff"><name>Two inch thing (2")</name><description>This thing is really "awesome"></description></xml>'
t = s.gsub(/(<description>)(.*?)(<\/description>)/) do
  open_tag, content, end_tag = $1, $2, $3
  content = content.gsub(/"/, '')  
  [open_tag, content, end_tag].join
end
p s
p t
```

Output:

```
"<xml attribute=\"stuff\"><name>Two inch thing (2\")</name><description>This thing is really \"awesome\"></description></xml>"
"<xml attribute=\"stuff\"><name>Two inch thing (2\")</name><description>This thing is really awesome></description></xml>"
```

*Limitations*: This is very specific to the exact format of the XML.  Many valid changes to the XML that do not change its meaning will break this code.  For external use only; use only as directed.  Stop taking this regular expression if serious side effects occur.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the minor issue in case (removing the quotation mark) and revealed the fact that the XML-file I was working on was corrupt. I don't think I would have seen that without this fix.